# "Listen to music" or  "listen for music"

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

1. The music for which we heard last night at the concert was exceptionally good.
2. The music to which we listened at the concert last night was exceptionally good.
3. The music which we listened last night at the concert was exceptionally good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Music is generally listened *to*.  We listen *for* things we are expecting -- the doorbell, the phone, the tornado sirens.

> The music to which we listened at the concert last night was exceptionally good.

This is the best choice, although it is clunky.  That being said, my suggested alternative is:

> The music we **heard** at the concert last night was exceptionally good.

Comment: And I'd suggest directly "Last night's concert was exceptionally good".  In context, all concerts have music and all music must be heard to be enjoyed.

Comment: @BobDuell There's truth in that, but it's reasonable to make clear that what you liked about the concert was the music itself, and not something else about the event. It would be quite plausible to say that the building where the concert was held was beautiful, or that you enjoyed spending time with your friends regardless of the quality of the music.

Comment: Not that there’s anything wrong with saying that the music we listened to last night was good. That “to which we listened” stuff is pretty silly, if you ask me.

Answer (score 5):

Only the second sentence is correct, although it would be much more natural to express the same as

“*The music **(which) we listened to** at the concert last night was exceptionally good,*
”

where the relative pronoun would be normally dropped in spoken language and could be preserved, or replaced by ***that***, if you wrote the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 is grammatically correct, though somewhat awkward. Constructions like "to which" are sometimes used to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition. It's more common to simply say, "The music we listened to at the concert last night was exceptionally good."

Number 1 is wrong because "heard" does not take a preposition. You could say, "We heard the music", but you DON'T say, "We heard for the music."

Number 3 is wrong because "listened" DOES require a preposition. You say, "We listened to the music", NOT "We listened the music."

(As to why "listened" requires a preposition but "heard" does not ... I think that's just a rule you have to learn word by word.)

Comment: Parallel with _see_ and _look at_.

Comment: Is parallel also 'speak' and 'talk about'? @Colin Fine

Comment: It's parallel insofar as _speak_ is transitive but _talk_ is not usually; but semantically it's nor really similar. In _hear/listen to_ and _see/look at_ each pair can take the same object, and differ only in intention. But _speak_ and _talk about_ are both intentional, but _speak_ takes the utterance as its object, while _talk about_ has the subject of the utterance.