# "Listen to music" vs. "listen to the music"

Tags: meaning, differences, definite-articles

English is not my mother tongue. I once came across information that *listening to music* and *listening to **the** music* mean something different. *Listening to **the** music* would mean you put whole heart into it, which can be evident by dance, other similar behaviour like improvised accompaniment or changes in face expression. Is this true?

Comment: No, it is false; and only the context can clarify the difference between these sentence.

Comment: *Music* is music but not any specific music; ***the** music* is specific music (exactly which specific music is determined by the context).

Comment: This is the strangest theory I have heard all month, hands down.

Comment: Doobie Brothers++

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71851/listen-to-music-or-listen-for-music) - *listen to music or listen for music*

Comment: @RegDwighт I also found it very strange, but I had to be sure.

Comment: @RegDwighт: You must get out more! I just found several more reasons to continue believing that [Elvis lives](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/elvisandtracy/Elvis%20Lives.htm)

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? Could it be done better? I tried to Google this expression and look in dictionaries but I haven't found anything except for, yes, Doobie Brothers song. Assume what I heard was true, what would be the way to learn about it?

Comment: The only possible reason I can see for downvoting this question is its omission of the source and context of your "information", which might explain how someone came to say something so (on its face) absurd. But that's not relevant to your question.

Comment: @StoneyB It might be it, thanks for the explanation. I think I heard this theory on English lesson or course but I can't be sure because it was a long time ago so I didn't want to include it.

Comment: It should be noted that "listen to the music" has an idiomatic/metaphoric meaning (as expressed in at least one song), meaning roughly "pay attention".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference is the definite article ('the') which means the second sentence refers to some specific music.

For example, as you put your iPod headphones on you might say "I am going to listen to music", meaning no particular music.

If you were in a park, and hear a band playing in the distance you might say "I am going to listen to the music", meaning that specific music you can hear now.

Neither of them is necessarily accompanied by dancing or changes in expression.

Answer (score 3):

"Listen to music" means listen to music in general.  In other words, go find some songs, put them on your MP3 player, and listen to them.

"Listen to the music" means there is music playing now and you should listen to it.  Not just vague music in general, but THE music that is playing now.

Listen to the radio is correct.  Listen to radio is wrong.

Comment: How is this answering the original post?  (Also, it is not wrong to say *Listen to radio!* - *Listen to radio, it's more rewarding than TV with its brash and distracting  moving images.*)

Comment: How is this not answering the original post? "the" is used to specify something.. The article is used before singular and plural nouns when the noun is specific or particular. Here, when we are talking about specific song/ music , we say Listen to the music.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to music is correct if you're going to tell someone but you're not doing it right now you can say I'm going to listen to the music.